# How to initialize c-strings array (no stl)

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, crt, c-strings

I want to initialize array of c-strings with zero pointers in MSVC2010

```
// Foo.h
#pragma once
class Foo {
  int sz_;
  char **arr_; 
public:
  Foo();
  ~Foo();
  // ... some other functions
};

// Foo.cpp
#include "Foo.h"
#define INITIAL_SZ 20

Foo::Foo() : sz_(INITIAL_SZ) {
  // there I have to initialize arr_ (dynamic array and can be enlarged later)
  arr_ = (char **)calloc(INITIAL_SZ * sizeof (char *)); // ??? 
  // or maybe arr_ = new ...
}
```

How to correct initialize `arr_`? I was not allowed to use of STL, MFC, etc.

Comment: Just curious. Why no STL? And also what have you tried so far? Actually what you have there `calloc()` will initialize everything to zeros (NULL).

Comment: If not for the `class` bit, I would have tagged this C...

Comment: @yasouser - It was a requirement of the customer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arr = new char*[INITIAL_SZ]();` will do - you can even put it in an initialization list.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to avoid STL, etc., then why not:

```
arr_ = new char*[INITIAL_SZ]();
```

You could even put this in the initializer list.

Remember to invoke `delete [] arr_` in your destructor.  (As @Nawaz points out below, you should probably also follow the Rule of Three, and define a suitable copy-constructor and assignment operator as well.)

Comment: I don't think it initializes them to zero, does it? (I'm not perfectly sure of the initialization rules, but I think the extra parentheses are needed)

Comment: And also define copy-ctor and assignment operator : rule of three!

Answer (score 2):

*1. Build a proper string class*

*2. Build a proper array class*

*3. Use the array on strings*

Happy chasing memory leaks, double frees and memory corruption.

Comment: Yes, except you didn't answer his question. "I was not allowed to use of STL, MFC, etc." Clearly he's following some specific guidelines, so your answer is completely unhelpful, if not a little stuck-up.

Comment: @leetNightshade: it's definitely stuck up, and meant as a taunt. However not using STL or MFC does not mean that you cannot create your own classes for memory management. My answer merely suggest to decompose the issue (String + Array) instead of trying to solve it all at once. And I know that the classes will be imperfect, experts get them wrong.

Comment: +1 a little extra work up front to avoid hours of painful string management and debugging by hand.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr_ = (char **)calloc(INITIAL_SZ * sizeof (char *));
```

should be

`arr_ = (char **)calloc(INITIAL_SZ, sizeof (char *));`

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to redefine `arr_` as `std::vector<std::string>` and to use `vector::reserve()` to hint at the number of strings you expect to have. Let C++ take care of the memory for you.

But if you *must* use raw C strings, you probably want:

```
arr_ = new char *[sz_];
```